# 3 month rolling Avg

Tags: sql-server, rolling-computation, rolling-average

Question: need help with query to show as a 3-month rolling average

This is what I currently have

```sql
SELECT
    Date,
    month(date) AS[Month],
    year(date) AS[Year],
    AVG(ALL Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date ASC) AS Average
FROM
    FactFinance
SELECT
    YEAR(Date) AS Year,
    MONTH(Date) AS Month,
    AVG(Amount) AS AvgAmt
FROM
    FactFinance
GROUP BY
    YEAR(Date),
    MONTH(Date)
ORDER BY
    Year,
    Month;
GO;
```

[SQL Statement 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAkUL.jpg)

[SQL Statement 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coV00.jpg)

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected results. Ideally in the form of DDL/DML statements to allow easy copy and paste.

Comment: But definitely not images...

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know what you are needed.

Comment: DDL/DML statements are `create table` and `insert into table` i.e. you provide the code to build the data to use to test your query against - because otherwise you're asking us to do that. However an alternative is to post the data as text so it can be copy and pasted out. You only need to look at a few other SO questions to see how this is done.

Comment: @Dale Burrell table is from AdventureworksDW2016CPT3 but probably any recentish version of adventureworks data warehouse is probably fine - it may be easier for you to download than the OP (contains 34000+ rows) create test data AND the issue is with the first query.

Answer (score 1):

2 things I would do to test this 1) pick a year to make the data more digestible 2) amend the second query to include a sum. The first query should be amended to pre-calculate the the monthly figures using a cte or a sub query (I have chosen to use a sub query) and you need to use the preceding.. clause to tell sql server over how many months you want

```
select  month,year,
        sum(amt) over (order by month,year  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND current row) sumamount,
        avg(amt) over (order by month,year  ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND current row) '3monthra'
from
(
SELECT  month(date) as [Month], 
        year(date) as [Year], 
        sum(Amount) amt,
        count(*) as cnt
FROM FactFinance 
GROUP BY YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]) 
) s
where year = 2005
order by year, month


SELECT 
        YEAR(Date) AS Year, 
        MONTH(Date) AS Month, 
        sum(amount) as sumamt,
        count(*) as cnt,
        AVG(Amount) AS AvgAmt 
FROM FactFinance 
where YEAR(Date) = 2005
GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
ORDER BY Year, Month; 

GO

month       year        sumamount               3monthra
----------- ----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
7           2005        11384884.51            11384884.51
8           2005        36016653.13            18008326.565
9           2005        58029544.31            19343181.4366667
10          2005        66734589.35            22244863.1166667
11          2005        79778854.28            26592951.4266667
12          2005        88791927.09            29597309.03

(6 row(s) affected)

Year        Month       sumamt                 cnt         AvgAmt
----------- ----------- ---------------------- ----------- ----------------------
2005        7           11384884.51            1130        10075.1190353982
2005        8           24631768.62            1122        21953.4479679145
2005        9           22012891.18            1116        19724.8128853047
2005        10          20089929.55            1122        17905.463057041
2005        11          37676033.55            1124        33519.6028024911
2005        12          31025963.99            1126        27554.1420870338

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Note this is taken from aw2012 , hopefully your version has 2005.

Comment: Thank you. How would this be written with CTE? That is the direction she is leading us to but seems way more complicated. Any help would be appreciated